# Cleaner way to require multiple Vue components?

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js, browserify, vue-component

I've just started working with Vue.JS and there's one small issue that's bugging me. My file structure similar to the following:

```
+ js
|--+ components
|  |-- parent.vue
|  |-- child.vue
|-- main.js
```

Then in my main.js I have the following:

```
window.Vue = require('vue');
require('vue-resource');
Vue.component('parent', require('./Components/parent'));
Vue.component('child', require('./Components/child'));
var app = new Vue({ el: "#app" });
```

(I'm not actually certain what `vue-resource` is, but this was set up for me by a fresh install of Laravel 5.3)

At a glance I immediately noticed that my main.js file was going to get unmanageable if I added too many components. I don't have this issue when working with ReactJS because main.js only needs to include the "parent" component, and the parent component includes the child component. I figured Vue.JS would have a similar trick to help me organize my components - but reading through the docs I didn't find one (maybe I missed it?)

Is there a way to **either** have a Vue component list its dependencies (for Browserify / Webpack to bundle) **or** recursively run a javascript statement on every file in a directory (so Browserify / Webpack just packs up the whole thing)?

I'm not concerned with async components at the moment - so if the solution breaks that functionality it will be okay. One day I would like to play around with using Webpack to create async components and only loading them as I need them, but today I'm more interested in just getting this up and running so I can play way Vuex.

Comment: You don't have to list out every component via `Vue.component` in the main JS file - that's only for global components. Each of your main components can require its own sub-components as needed without polluting the root level file. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html

Comment: vue-resource: https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `Vue.component` syntax is for global components only, if you have a component that is being used inside another component use this:

```
import Parent from './components/Parent.vue';
import Child from './components/Child.vue';

new Vue({ 
  el: "#app", 
  components: { Parent, Child } 
});
```

Than inside this components you can use the other components.

The only advantage of using `Vue.component(Parent)` is that you can use this `<parent></parent>` component globaly in all your other components without declaring them implicitly.

Good Luck :)

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to import everything at the top level.

In your `main.js` you can import the Parent component

```
import Parent from './components/Parent.vue'

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  components: {
    Parent
  }
})
```

With your `Parent.vue`

```
<template>
  <div>
    <p>I am the parent</p>
    <child></child>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import Child from './Child.vue'

  export default {
    mounted() {
      console.log('mounted parent')
    }
  }
</script>

<style scoped>
  // ...
</style>
```

Then in your `Child.vue`

```
<template>
  <p>I am the child</p>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    mounted() {
      console.log('mounted child')
    }
  }
</script>

<style scoped>
  // ...
</style>
```

And you should end up with

```
<div>
  <p>I am the parent</p>
  <p>I am the child</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way, not sure if it's the best in terms of performance and webpack chunk size. I created an `index.js` file in the components root:

```
export const HelloWorld = require('./HelloWorld.vue').default
```

So, inside the components I would use:

```
const { HelloWorld } = require('@/components')
```

Due to babel issues I need to make a mix of `require` and `export`, also the use of `default` attribute after require — as I read in some babel use discussions.